# knockout change event on input: validation - set focus if invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a table bound by knockout, with input fields in. I am successfully using the change event to validate one of the inputs, but I am struggling with this:

how do I get knockout to set the focus back to the input if the input's data doesnt meet with my requirements?

I've tried returning false to prevent bubble through, but this leaves focus on the next input in the tr.

markup:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    mynamespace.myVm.myModel = new personalInfoViewModel();

    ko.applyBindings(mynamespace.myVmument.getElementById('divMyTable'));
  }
</script>
<div id='divMyTable'>
  <table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: mynamespace.myVm.myModel">
      <tr data-bind="event: { change: $root.markDirtyRow }">
        <td><input data-bind="value: dto.PersonId,
                              event: { change: $root.validateId }"></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: dto.someValue"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

knockout:

```
var personInfoViewModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  var self.myModel = ko.observableArray();

  self.validateId = function (record) {
    if (doValidate(record.PersonId)) {  // for example
      self.UserData(record.PersonId);
      return true;
    } else {
      alert("Person Id " + record.PersonId + " is not recognised.");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use the [knockout `hasFocus` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html). When it's `true`, the element gets the focus.

NOTE: in most cases, instead of using a change event, you should use a computed to determine if a value in an input is valid or not. You can use events with KO, but it's not the natural way to do what you want. For example, you can create a computed named `valid`, and use a binding like this: `data-bind="hasFocus: !valid()"`.

You should have a look a this, which will help you a lot with validation in KO: [Knockout Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation)

Comment: Then test it, and if this is aproblem, add a new question. IE is officially supported from IE 6 to IE11: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/browser-support.html

Comment: I'm not worried about ancient browsers, we're targeting IE10+ for those who still insist on IE.

Comment: @JimFR sorry, I was answering G_S's comment

Comment: That's ok, so was I. It seemed relevant to reply :)